# Parametrize source property in go.Picture object

Tags: gojs

I'm using gojs to drop images from pallette on canvas, I have created Picture object and now I need to parametrize its source property to set path to image user currently clicked and wants to drag-drop

this is how my code looks like:

```
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    go.GraphObject.make(go.Node, "Spot",
        go.GraphObject.make(go.Picture, {
                scale: 0.3,
                // source1: currentlyGrabbedDevicePath
                // source2: '../img/devices/hub1.png'
            },
            // new go.Binding('source', 'cgdp')
        ),
        /*more code below..*/
```

- **source2** obviously works
- **source1** does not ( im getting empty container without width/height. Scaling is being ignored - which I need, I cant be setting statis width/height for all images )
- **binding**  same ( empty container without width/height )

Answer (score 0):

In your code to set **Picture.source** to the expression `currentlyGrabbedDevicePath`, I'll bet that it evaluated to `undefined` at the time you defined the template.  That's the same as not setting **Picture.source** at all, so all instances of those Nodes will have Pictures that do not have the source set.

Using a Binding seems sensible.  Did you make sure that the node data object has the `cgdp` property set to the URL that you want?  If you are setting it dynamically, are you using **Model.setDataProperty** so that notifications happen and so that Bindings are evaluated and so that undo/redo history is maintained?